# How to add a top title above the header line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to add a TITLE just above header using Pandas script.

```
Sl_No  Departure    Arrival
 1      UK          India
 2      US          India        
 3      France      India
 4      New York    Singapore
 5      Tokyo       Singapore
```

I tried the below script but I'm not sure what changes I need to do in order to add TTITLE(top title)

```
    import os
    os.chdir("/dev/alb_shrd/alb/alb_prj/Files/albt/alt/scrpts")
    
    # Reading the csv file
    
    import pandas as pd
    print(pd.__file__)
    col_names=["Sl_No","Departure","Arrival"]
    
    df_new  = pd.read_csv("SourceFile.csv", quotechar='"',names=col_names, sep="|",skiprows=1, low_memory=False,error_bad_lines=False,header=None).dropna(axis=1, how="all")
    
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["TOP TITLE"],list(df_new.columns)])
df_new.head()

pd.DataFrame(df_new.to_numpy(), None , columns = header).head()
   
    
    # Saving xlsx file
    
    file = f"SourceFile_{pd.Timestamp('now').strftime('%Y%m%d_%I%M')}.xlsx"
    df_new.to_excel(file, index=False)
```

Can anyone guide me how to add title at the top of the excel?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting a row above pandas column headers to save a title name in the first cell of csv / excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459258/inserting-a-row-above-pandas-column-headers-to-save-a-title-name-in-the-first-ce)

Comment: I tried adding these lines but it didn't work:                                                          
 header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["TOP TITLE"],list(df_new.columns)])
df_new.head()

pd.DataFrame(df_new.to_numpy(), None , columns = header).head()

Comment: Can you try `df_new.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["TOP TITLE"],list(df_new.columns)])` instead `header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["TOP TITLE"],list(df_new.columns)])
df_new.head()

pd.DataFrame(df_new.to_numpy(), None , columns = header).head()` ?

Comment: Getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Looks like I'm missing something in the script